# Python Scipy - Solve same scalar equation for two different variables

Tags: python, scipy

In my algorithm I need to solve the same equation twice for two different variables. At the moment I am using scipy.fsolve and I have defined two different functions respectively for the first and second iteration.

The first time I solve for X and I pass a certain number of parameters, including Y.
The second time I need to solve for Y while X becomes one of the parameters. Of course, in this second iteration some of the original parameters also need to be changed.

This is the simplified code

```
def f1(X, *params1):
    (Y, a, b, c) = params1
    long procedure...
    return S
def f2(Y, *params2):
    (X, a, b, c) = params2
    same long procedure....
    return S
params1 = (Y, a1, b1, c1)
X = fsolve(f1, X0, args=params1)
params2 = (X, a1, b2, c2)
Y = fsolve(f2, Y0, args=params2)
```

Is there a way to organize the code in a more elegant way, by reusing the same function?

Comment: As shown your question is unclear - f1 and f2 are not used, and the fsolve's don't have a function in them. If all you are doing in the desired function is swapping X for Y, than that is easy to do using parameters in the call to the functions in fsolve(). Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks. Is it clearer now? i could post the actual code but it's quite long.

Comment: So in f1 and f2, is the only difference that you are swapping X and Y? That is, can you just call X = fsolve(f1,X0, args=params1) and then Y = fsolve(f1, Y0, args=params2)? Or are X and Y being used in different places?  That is, the function is f(X,Y,a,b,c,...) and they are independent?  If this is the case you can use a lambda to call with varying X and fixed Y, then fixed X and varying Y.

Comment: Please just post a short but complete piece of code that actually runs, maybe with a small amount of fake data, etc.  This will make your question clearer, and you'll get better (and more likely tested) answers.

Comment: OK. Can't really shorten the code as it has several constants and internal procedures. The github repositories is [here](https://github.com/Rojj/PyMaps/blob/master/petf.py) Hope this works. Thanks for looking